# Artificial neural network activation function

Tags: backpropagation

I've programmed an ANN with backpropagation algorithm to forecast number of customers with 3 layers, 1 output neuron, 3 hidden neurons and 4 input neurons. so i need a continuous output. what activation functions should I use?

Comment: Tanh or a logistic function or something like that, these are the common cases. Do you have any special requirement?

Comment: what is the range of these functions? i want to have a number between 100 and 10000 in output. what should i do?

Comment: You can scale them to whatever you need by multiplying and/or adding some constants. Tanh has range (-1,1) and the logistic function has range (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you can do (and I've seen this works well) is to apply a PureLin function to the input and output layer and use the Tanh or Sigmod in the hidden layers. The rest of the work is done by the weights!

Hope this helps!